# Getting screen brightness in a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

I'm trying to get current screen brightness in my Linux kernel module. However, I don't know how can I access the brightness variable, though easily get it in an user-space application using the sysfs interface.

Please let me know a clue about this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are into kernel module programming, peeking at the sysfs filesystem code should not be that hard.

Comment: Yeah. I'm doing now, but I could not find any clues because I'm a newbie in kernel module programming.

Answer (score 4):

Usually modern Desktops (GNOME/XFCE4/KDE) provide utilities to change the brightness but answering your question you should look on your `/sys/class` directory for it. HINT: look for `backlight` you will find one driver which provides you that functionality.

In my case it is samsung-laptop module and intel.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
$ cat actual_brightness
```

This worked to get the actual brightness.You might want to go to `/sys/class/backlight` and try to `ls` to see whats in store.

Answer (score 0):

You can change directory to /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0 and then open actual_brightness file.

```
cd /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0
cat actual_brightness
```